# is there a way to generate a password and output in a file in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I'm installing a tool using Terraform and I want to supply the password using Terraform and destroy the resource permanently.

I know I can generate a random string using this

```
  resource "random_password" "password" {
  length           = 16
  special          = true
  override_special = "!#$%&*()-_=+[]{}<>:?"
  }
```

But cannot find a way to destroy it. As in, it is always visible in the statefile.
I would like to output the string into a file and not be retrievable.

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: "I'm installing a tool using Terraform" normally one uses a software provisioner in conjunction with Terrafrom for this. It would definitely prove easier for you.

Comment: Welp thanks for responding at least. I'm thinking of writing a seperate script and have Terraform pick it up as a variable. Couldn't think of a better way.